# Prevent pushing of commits that add to closed branches

Tags: mercurial, branch

How can I configure a Mercurial server to restrict commits to a named branch once it has been closed? I only want the repository administrator to have the ability to reopen the branch.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PruningDeadBranches says that closed changesets can be identified by "close=1 in the changeset's extra field". It's not clear how to read a changeset's extra field using the [Mercurial API](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MercurialApi).

Comment: Damn right! It _should_ be easier to stop people accidentally committing to closed branches.

Comment: Everyone keeps saying "committing" but you mean "pushing".  You'll never prevent a determined committer, you just reject their push.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an ACL extension that is distributed along with Mercurial.
You should be able to specify the frozen branches by denying commit to every one except the administrator. I am not sure if named branches can leverage this facility.

- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/AclExtension

Configuring acls:

```
[acl.deny.branches] 
frozen-branch = *

[acl.allow.branches]
branch_name = admin
```

Answer (score 4):

A server can't restrict commits, but it can refuse to accept pushes that violate constraints.  Here's a hook you can put on a server to reject any pushes that have any changesets that are on a closed branch:

```
#!/bin/sh
for thenode in $(hg log -r $HG_NODE:tip --template '{node}\n') ; do
     if hg branches --closed | grep -q "^$(hg id --branch -r $thenode).*\(closed\)"  ; then
          echo Commits to closed branches are not allowed -- bad changeset $thenode
          exit 1
     fi
done
```

You'd install that hook like this:

```
[hooks]
prechangegroup = /path/to/that.sh
```

There's almost certainly a way to do it using in-python hooks with the API you referenced, but shell hooks work out pretty well too.

Comment: Though I cannot downvote this answer, it should be noted that this does not work because $HG_NODE is not available for prechangegroup. Fixing the hook to pretxnchangegroup does not work either, unfortunately, because then the change for whether or not the branch is closed does no longer work as pretxnchangegroup does tentatively add the changesets and as such the branch is already reopened. I would prefer to write a shell hook but still wonder how to do this for the specific purpose discussed here.

Comment: I got this work to work. What you can do is use the pretxnchangegroup hook and use a script similar to the one listed above that checks for each node in $HG_NODE:tip whether one of its parents have "close=1" in its extra fields. You can use hg log -r $parentNode --template '{extras}' | grep -q "close=1" to do the latter check.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an in-process hook that should reject additional changesets on a closed branch.

```
from mercurial import context, ui
def run(ui, repo, node, **kwargs):
    ctx = repo[node]
    for rev in xrange(ctx.rev(), len(repo)):
        ctx = context.changectx(repo, rev)
        parent1 = ctx.parents()[0]
        if parent1 != None and parent1.extra().get('close'):
            ui.warn("Commit to closed branch is forbidden!\n")
            return True
    return False
```

The hook can run in pretxncommit mode (checked during a local commit transaction) or pretxnchangegroup mode (checked when changesets added from external repo) with the following hgrc entries:

```
[hooks]
pretxncommit.forbid_commit_closed_branch = python:/path/to/forbid_commit_closed_branch.py:run
pretxnchangegroup.forbid_commit_closed_branch = python:/path/to/forbid_commit_closed_branch.py:run
```

Not sure if this hook will work with Mercurial versions prior to 2.2.