# Preventing users from committing when the branch is close

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs

Is there a way to prevent users from committing without using `--force` when a branch is closed?
Another way is to ask if I am sure I want to commit and act accordingly.
Is there such a way to do it using a hook/extension?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961548/prevent-commits-to-closed-branches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be easy to write a hook to do it: write a pre-commit hook that checks if the current parent is closed (by inspecting the "extra" changeset metadata field).

For documentation, start here: http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html. You may also want to look at the output of hg help hooks.

Comment: Could you refer me to the right documentation? I never wrote a hook before.

Comment: I did, there is no mention to the extra metadata field or any api docs at all as far as I can see. Maybe I just haven't looked good enough.